# how to resize image in wordpress plugin developmennt

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin, and use custom metabox of an image, how can i resize image dynamically to display on front. 
i am using this function but it not works

```
add_image_size( 'photos', 100, 100, true );
```

Comment: Show your code on how you add the action in your plug in. Do you have something like `add_action('some-hook', 'add_image_func')` to add the functionality to the theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_get_image_editor()`

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor( 'cool_image.jpg' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
    $image->resize( 300, 300, true );
    $image->save( 'new_image.jpg' );
}
```